# First time XeLaTeX UTF8 bibliography in TeXworks

Tags: bibliographies, xetex

I see people having various problems related to bibliographies in TEX.SE, but I cannot really benefit from answers, because I'm not sure how to use any bibliography let alone UTF8.

Could anybody paste a minimal working example citing a website and a tell how to compile it (it appears to be different than simply compiling a .tex)?

Edit: I realize how lame this thread looks, but I honestly could not find an exact tutorial, because it's either pdflatex, non-UTF8, not TeXworks or whatever people talking about...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example file, which requires `biber`, and can be compiled with `xelatex`. Use the following commands: `xelatex <filename>.tex`, `biber <filename>.bcf`, `xelatex <filename>.tex` --- where '`<filename>`' is whatever you called the example file.  (Note I don't have complicated UTF8 needs for my bibliography, so I added one entry full of gibberish; but compare the `junkentry` input with the image given below to see that `biber` handles the material properly, whereas `bibtex` would choke and produce the *wrong* gibberish.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}%
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[french,ngerman,italian,british]{babel}
\usepackage[strict=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, babel=hyphen, style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{congar1958,
  author =   {Congar, Y. M.-J.},
  title =    {\foreignlanguage{latin}{Quod omnes tangit ab
              omnibus tractari et approbari debet}},
  shorttitle = {Quod omnes tangit},
  journal =  {Revue historique de droit français et étranger},
  date =     1958,
  volume =   36,
  pages =    {210--259},
  series =   {4e sér.},
  hyphenation =  {french},
}
@InCollection{flueler1992,
  author =   {Flüeler, Christoph},
  title =    {Die Rezeption der \quotedblbase Politica`` des
              Aristoteles an der Pariser Artistenfakultät im
              13.\@ und 14.\@ Jahrhundert},
  shorttitle = {Die Rezeption der \quotedblbase Politica``},
  booktitle = {Das Publikum politischer Theorie im 14.\@ Jahrhundert},
  pages =    {127--138},
  date =     1992,
  editor =   {Miethke, Jürgen},
  location = {Munich},
  publisher = {R. Oldenbourg Verlag},
  series =   {Schriften des Historischen Kollegs, Kolloquien},
  number =   21,
  hyphenation =  {german}}

@Book{tocco1910,
  editor =  {Tocco, Felice},
  title =   {La Quistione della povertà nel secolo XIV
             secondo nuovi documenti},
  shorttitle = {La Quistione},
  publisher = {Francesco Perrella},
  date =    1910,
  location = {Naples},
  hyphenation = {italian},
}

@Book{junkentry,
  author =      {Zß§œíáßó¼¾j},
  title =       {A «Fake» þíþøé},
  date =        9999,
  location =    {Nusquama},
  publisher =   {Apud nullum - ¥ - óé®jgððj§ØŒG®Ír},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

For those who'd like to stick with the `pdfTeX` engine (and thereby use `latex` or `pdflatex`), just comment out the `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` lines, and load fonts and encodings in your accustomed way.  For example, the following image was made with `pdflatex` and the following packages instead of `fontspec`:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
```

[image]

Comment: Quick question out of ignorance: Does using `biblatex` compel us to switch from `pdflatex` to `xelatex` ? Does your code work on `pdflatex` and `biber` with `utf8/utf8x` `inputenc` ?

Comment: Replace `\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}%` with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to work with `pdflatex`and `biber`. Is it possible show the reference-output.pdf in answer to crosscheck for benefit of all ?. It works now for me with `pdflatex` on Linux with replacements.`Junk entry` is confusing for me. could you add something like earlier references or remove it ?`

Comment: may be it's worth mentioning "handling of any character type " when compared to bibtex  to show the power of `biblatex`. I could not understand which language it means, because gibberish characters might also come due to improper font encoding errors also, so newbies might get confused.

Comment: @texenthusiast -- OK, I added to the first paragraph.